# Is there a way to read chrome's "safe browsing" files?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I was looking through my appdata and I noticed that in < AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data > there are files that start with "Safe Browsing" and ending in "Bloom, Bloom prefix set, cookies, cookies-journal, csd whitelist, download, download whitelist, extension blacklist, and ip blacklist".

How can I view whats inside these files?

Comment: Any luck finding something?

Answer (score 0):

I use File Viewer lite. It can view about 120 file types including all of the ones you just listed. I'm not sure what you mean by "read" though, because the file content is encrypted. Hope this helps!

Comment: "Hope this helps" is not helpful. You could test if the files are readable with your tool, then you would actually answer the question.